# Approximating a shape boundary using Fourier descriptors

Tags: c++, image-processing, fft, approximation, boundary

I am trying to approximate shape boundaries by using Fourier descriptors. I know this can be done because I've learned about it in class and read about it in several sources.

To obtain the Fourier descriptors of a boundary of (x,y) coordinates, I do the following:
1) Turn (x,y) coordinates into complex numbers of the form x + iy
2) Feed this new set of numbers into the 1D Fourier transform
3) The output are the Fourier descriptors

To approximate the boundary, I simply remove (set to zero) the high frequencies, then apply the inverse Fourier transform, then convert the complex numbers back to (x,y) coordinates, and then reconstruct the image from this new set of coordinates. The goal of my project is to find out how well I can approximate boundaries depending on how many of the terms I set to zero.

My problem is that whenever I set ANY of the frequencies to 0, my output image is very small and comes out as very weird patterns.

I've included an example below. The input image is a normal square. The first output image given is the reconstruction of the image using all the Fourier descriptors as normal. Note that the whole boundary is not there because the number of boundary pixels was sampled to 256 and I didn't bother connecting the dots when I output. Also note that the output is translated to the bottom left corner, this was on purpose. The second output image is when I use only the first 128 frequencies.

[Input Image http://img19.imageshack.us/my.php?image=square0.bmp](http://img19.imageshack.us/my.php?image=square0.bmp)

[Output Image 1: All frequencies http://img27.imageshack.us/my.php?image=square0normal.bmp](http://img27.imageshack.us/my.php?image=square0normal.bmp)

[Output Image 2: First half of frequencies http://img23.imageshack.us/my.php?image=square0out.bmp](http://img23.imageshack.us/my.php?image=square0out.bmp)

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

**Edit:** First time putting images on here, not sure why they aren't showing up.. here are the links:
[Input image](http://img19.imageshack.us/my.php?image=square0.bmp)
[Output1](http://img27.imageshack.us/my.php?image=square0normal.bmp)
[Output2](http://img23.imageshack.us/my.php?image=square0out.bmp)

Also here is a [link to a document that talks about this a bit](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/MORSE/boundary-rep-desc.pdf), it starts at the end of page 5.

Comment: I'd try normalizing image coordinates to [0,1] interval before feeding the Fourier transform, and then denormalizing at the output.

Comment: It seems that you are loosing precision but it doesn't seems related to the Fourier transform because the first output look right. Did you try another picture? I'd suggest something asymmetric.

Comment: Would this actually affect the results other than maybe the scale of the image? I don't really see how..

Comment: I tried a couple other pictures, one of a circle, and one of an imperfect T-shape, and both worked fine when I use all the descriptors, but both are very wrong when I use anything less than all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you are getting is what would be expected if you threw out the low frequencies instead of the high ones. Are you sure about which frequencies are which?

Comment: Apparently the low frequencies are the last few descriptors, not the first few... I just reversed which frequencies get zeroed and it works fine now, thanks!

Comment: Just realized that I was wrong again, and that the descriptors in the middle of the array are the low frequencies, so I zeroed them outwards from the center and it works so much better now